# HTML5 audio in IE9

Tags: html, audio

I've got a curious problem with IE9+ and the HTML5 audio tag.

Have a look at this site: https://www.phasetrax.de/artist/Chryso/album/42/lipstick-of-the-reddest-color

In Firefox,Chrome and Safari it's working correctly, but in IE9+ I'm just getting a black field with a red sign for the audio element.

I've also checked the HTML header for the OGG source, and for me it's looking good.

```
curl -k -I https://www.phasetrax.de//cdn/song/323/lipstick-of-the-reddest-color.ogg
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.2.0
Date: Sat, 30 Mar 2013 14:59:50 GMT
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Connection: keep-alive
Status: 200 OK
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="01_Lipstick_Of_The_Reddest_Color.ogg"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Cache-Control: private
X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
```

here's the audio element code:

```
<audio controls autobuffer  id="pt_player_1">
<source class="mp3_src" src="https://www.phasetrax.de//cdn/song/323/lipstick-of-the-reddest-color.mp3">
<source class="ogg_src" src="https://www.phasetrax.de//cdn/song/323/lipstick-of-the-reddest-color.ogg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element. Get newest
  Firefox!
</audio>
```

The app which is responsible for serving the ogg is Rails with Unicorn and NGINX.

Maybe, anyone knows what's going wrong with IE in this case.. or better said, what am I doing wrong?

Regards, Alex

Comment: The ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, and nginx tags are not relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with a different audio and it works properly.
I think your audio bitrate has something to do with this. 
Try 128kbps 44khz mono. And you can try other combinations through trial and error.

I use format factory for these audio conversions.

Comment: yeah, it seems like IE9 is buggy with some bitrates.